# adding admob is not working to working AllJoyn xcode project

Tags: ios, alljoyn

I am new to Iphone Development.
I am using alljoyn framework .project is working fine but when i added admob libraries (followed this [link](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#ios) ), it gives me error.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/Maaz/Desktop/Alljoyn_sdk/alljoyn-3.4.3-osx_ios-sdk/alljoyn_objc/samples/iOS/AllJoynChat/../../../../alljoyn_core/build/darwin/arm/iphonesimulator/Debug/dist/cpp/lib"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/Maaz/Desktop/Alljoyn_sdk/openssl-1.0.1f/build/Debug-iphonesimulator"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/Maaz/Desktop/Alljoyn_sdk/alljoyn-3.4.3-osx_ios-sdk/alljoyn_objc/samples/iOS/AllJoynChat/../../../../alljoyn_core/build/darwin/i386/iphonesimulator/Debug/dist/cpp/lib"'
ld: library not found for -lalljoyn
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

anybody knows then plz help I will appreciate.

thanx,
moaz

Comment: Your compiler has the incorrect path for the library, so it is throwing the error! Remove all the references of the library and try re adding. And also check whether the path /Users/Maaz/Desktop/Alljoyn_sdk/alljoyn-3.4.3-osx_ios-sdk/alljoyn_objc/samples/iOS/AllJoynChat/../../../../alljoyn_core/build/darwin/arm/iphonesimulator/Debug/dist/cpp/lib contains your library or not.

Comment: thanx @Harsh for your reply.you are right problem is with library search path.but i dont know what happens to it automatically after adding admob because before that it was wotking fine.

Comment: Is it still not working?

Comment: yes it started working as I found reason on another forum " Xcode 5.01 change the path of these three items when you add any type of library to it. You just need to rechange it to the original one. " 
So I used previously working project in xcode 4.6 and added admob in it and it worked fine.
and after that I used that that project in xcode 5 and it is working now with admob.I didnt got actual solution ,but it started working.

Comment: @MoazSaeed, I am stucked with the same problem i.e. ld: library not found for -lalljoyn, can you plz tell me where to find this lib or the path?

Comment: @mAc Sorry as m not expert with library path.
adding admob in xcode 5 project was causing problem.
So I used project in xcode 4.6 .
I added admob there and they worked and no path issue.
and i just used same project in xcode 5 afterwords and it started working.
no library added or path change.(as i mentioned above).
so again if you say technically it is not a technical solution but it is trivial solution.

Answer (score 0):

Alljoyn darwin project does not have a config to build with i386. I think they are working on this.